# An event that deletes all invites, unless it's from a certain guild

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make an event where it will delete all discord invites, but if the invite is from a specific specified guild, it won't delete it. This is what I currently have, it would be great if you could tell me how I can fix it!

````
async def on_message(message):
    guild1 = client.get_guild(884150367884025897)
    invites = await guild1.invites()
    for invite in invites:
        if invite.code == code:
            pass
    else:
        await message.delete()```
````

Comment: What issue are you currently having? What does or doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to do with the "if invite.code == code:" part, in specific == "code". I was told I needed it a while back. Nothing happens at this time.

Comment: Where did you define `code` at? Or did you not define it at all?